# AWK compare two files, match first field, paste data, and more

Tags: text, awk

I have this script, it is used to compare the first field from two files,
I want it to ignore cases, tried to add a line IGNORECASE = 1; but doesn't seem to work,

can you tell how to ignore cases?

```
BEGIN {
   FS=OFS=";"
}

FNR==NR {
   array[$1]=$2
   next
}

{
   if ($1 in array) { 
      print $1";" array[$1]";" $2
   }

   else {
      if ($2 in values) {
         print  $1";" "only_at_" FILENAME ";" $0 " same path    as " values[$2]
      }
      else {
         print  $1";" "only_at_" FILENAME ";" $0 " no path  found"
      }
   }
   values[$2]=$1
}
```

Let's say I have

File1

```
\\FILE48\bucan-CFAN_Subcommittees;\\SERVER24\dfs\Shared\can\CFAN Subcommittees
```

File2

```
\\file48\bucan-CFAN_Subcommittees;/fs8_100g/FILE48/BU/can/CFAN Subcommittees
\\FILE58\userhome_e;/fs1_100g/FILE58/userhome
```

Expected output

```
\\FILE48\bucan-CFAN_Subcommittees;\\SERVER24\dfs\Shared\can\CFAN Subcommittees;/fs8_100g/FILE48/BU/can/CFAN Subcommittees
\\MLISFILE58\userhome_e;only_at_file2;\\MLISFILE58\userhome_e;/fs1_100g/MLISFILE58/userhome no path found
```

Comment: please edit your question to include sample inputs and required output.  That said, the easiest solution (if I understand your problem), would be to convert the initial input with `toupper($2)` and do the comparison in your `else` like `if(toupper($2) in values)`. Good luck.

Comment: From the `gawk` `man` page: "NOTE: Array subscripting is not affected." So shellter's suggestion would be the way to go.

Comment: I added more information

Comment: please add sample output for the "only_at_" cases. Also, you can get more people working on your problem, by making the sample input simpler (and especially shorter). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple with the [`join`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=join) command

```
join -t';' -i -j 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 File1 File2
```

Using ";" as a field separator, case-insensitively join the two files on field 1, and output the first and second fields from file1 and the 2nd field from file2.

If you really want awk, this will do the same thing:

```
awk '
   BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} 
   NR==FNR {key[tolower($1)] = $0; next} 
   tolower($1) in key {print key[tolower($1)], $2}
 ' file1 file2
```